# How do I stop the text from moving when hovered? (background-image is involved)

Tags: html, css, positioning, background-image

This is basically the problem that I am facing now, http://jsfiddle.net/NCJeP/.

### HTML

```
      <nav>
    <ul id="city-navigation">
        <li><a href="../chennai/" class="active">Chennai</a></li>
        <li><a href="../trichy/">Trichy</a></li>
        <li><a href="../madurai/">Madurai</a></li>
        <li><a href="../coimbatore/">Coimbatore</a></li>
        <li><a href="../salem/">Salem</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>​
```

### CSS

```
#city-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#city-navigation li a {
    float: left;
    font: 14px Rockwell, Georgia, Times, “Times New Roman”, serif;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#city-navigation li a:hover {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/QVzKG.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    width: 116px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

#city-navigation .active {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/HbLa1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    width: 116px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

I can't seem to figure out how I can stop the text from moving to the right because of the extra width that the background image adds. I know there is enough space, I just want the image & text to be static.

If anyone can help out, I'd be very much thankful! =) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width on your hover is causing the jump. I moved it to the "a" tag and cleaned up the other code a bit as well:

```
#city-navigation li a {
    float: left;
    font: 14px Rockwell, Georgia, Times, “Times New Roman”, serif;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 116px;
    height: 60px;
}
#city-navigation li a:hover {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/QVzKG.png) no-repeat;
    color: #000;
}
#city-navigation .active {
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/HbLa1.png) no-repeat;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: This one works perfectly, I understand what I did wrong now! :) Should've set the width beforehand instead of adding it while on hover! Thank you for that, and thanks for the clean up as well.. I guess I was experimenting so much that I forgot to keep my code clean! :D

Answer (score 1):

Remove the width property from `#city-navigation .active` and `#city-navigation li a:hover`, which is causing the width to increase when you hover the list item.

Which will make your css code look like

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

#city-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#city-navigation li a {
    float: left;
    font: 14px Rockwell, Georgia, Times, “Times New Roman”, serif;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    color: #FFF;
}

#city-navigation li a:hover {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/QVzKG.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
}

#city-navigation .active {
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/HbLa1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}​
```

Comment: did you saw the fiddle of this?

Comment: your background-image is cropping

Comment: That would make the background image look incomplete, I want the full rounded rectangle to be shown while hovered.

In case you didn't try it out on jsFiddle, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/NCJeP/2/

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NCJeP/3/)

Thought I've not cleaned up for you but use `inline-block` and take out unnecessary margins around your navigation..

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: red;
}

#city-navigation {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
}

#city-navigation li a {
    float: left;
    font: 14px Rockwell, Georgia, Times, “Times New Roman”, serif;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 116px;
    text-align: center;
}

#city-navigation li a:hover {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/QVzKG.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    width: 116px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

#city-navigation .active {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/HbLa1.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
    width: 116px;
    height: 60px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Adding width on the main link, the same what @MediaGirl has shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13023740/1248133 =) Thank you for your input as well! :)